# MS SQL Server - Bulk insert from local file - How to indicate path on Mac OS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, path, bulkinsert

I have just created an empty SQL table called "claims" with its attributes using Aqua Data Studio. SQL standard is based on Microsoft SQL Server Express via Docker (a VM for Mac OS). Now I am trying to fill it in via Bulk insert statement from a local csv file called "claims.csv", like this:

```
BULK INSERT Claims
FROM 'Users/Antonio/wd/hhp/data/Claims.csv'
WITH
(
MAXERRORS = 0,
FIRSTROW = 2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

But I get the following error:

> [Error] Script lines: 1-9 --------------------------
>    Id 4860, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>       Cannot bulk load. The file "Users/Antonio/wd/hhp/data/Claims.csv" does not exist or you don't have file access rights.
>    Msg: 4860, Level: 16, State: 1, Procedure: , Line: 1

What am I doing wrong? am I specifying the path to file incorrectly? Many thx.

Comment: I am facing same problem.                                                                  Msg 4860, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Cannot bulk load. The file "/Users/amreshpandey/SimpsonParadoxCase/comParadox.csv" does not exist or you don't have file access rights. However amreshpandey$ open /Users/amreshpandey/SimpsonParadoxCase/comParadox.csv
works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have your path set incorrectly. Try:

```
BULK INSERT Claims
FROM 'C:/Users/Antonio/wd/hhp/data/Claims.csv'
WITH
(
MAXERRORS = 0,
FIRSTROW = 2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

Comment: I got the same error. I am using Mac OS Sierra 10.12.5, by the way.

Comment: @Antonio-Serrano oh I assumed windows due to the DB type... Either way, It looks like you're missing the full  path.

Comment: Any solution so far.

Comment: Msg 4860, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Cannot bulk load. The file "/Users/amreshpandey/SimpsonParadoxCase/comParadox.csv" does not exist or you don't have file access rights. However amreshpandey$ open /Users/amreshpandey/SimpsonParadoxCase/comParadox.csv
works.